# Room relations: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: java, android, android-room

I need to track trips made by users. A trip consists of start km and an end km to calculate the total distance passed in that trip in addition to places the user went to. So in the app when creating a new trip the user can enter those details and choose some places from a list.

My case is similar to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many). A playlist with songs. So I followed that guide to achieve it. I started without adding places just to make sure the app works fine and can query from/to the database without any errors.

Now I need to update a trip when places are added. I had this DAO method:

```java
@Update
void updateTrip(Trip trip);
```

but when I changed it to:

```java
@Transaction
@Update
void updateTrip(TripWithPlaces trip);
```

it gives compile error when trying to run the app:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    void updateTrip(TripWithPlaces trip);
                                   ^
```

(same thing for delete)

Some answers here said to update the version but the answers were a little old back to previous version of room.

My current dependencies versions:

```
// Kotlin
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

// Room
def room_version = "2.5.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// Lifecycle
def lifecycle_version = '2.6.2'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

I tried updating:

- **kotlin-bom** to `1.9.10`
- **room** to `2.6.0-rc01`
- **lifecycle** to `2.7.0-alpha02`

but no luck I still get the same error when trying to run the app.

---

### Codes:

**PlaceDao:**

```java
@Dao
public interface PlaceDao {

    @Insert
    void addPlace(Place place);

    @Update
    void updatePlace(Place place);

    @Delete
    void deletePlace(Place place);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM place WHERE place_id = :id")
    LiveData<Place> getPlaceByID(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM place")
    LiveData<List<Place>> getAllPlaces();

}
```

**TripDao:**

```java
@Dao
public interface TripDao {

    @Insert
    void addTrip(Trip trip);
    
    @Transaction
    @Update
    void updateTrip(TripWithPlaces trip);
    
    @Delete
    void deleteTrip(Trip trip);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM trip WHERE trip_id = :id")
    LiveData<TripWithPlaces> getTripByID(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM trip")
    LiveData<List<Trip>> getAllTrips();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM trip")
    LiveData<List<TripWithPlaces>> getTripsWithPlaces();

}
```

**Place** entity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "place")
public class Place {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_id")
    private int placeID;

    private String name;

    private String city;

    // constructors, getters, setters

}
```

**Trip** entity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "trip")
public class Trip {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "trip_id")
    private int tripID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_km")
    private double startKm;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_km")
    private double endKm;

    private TripStatus status;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    private long createdAt;

    // constructors, getters, setters

}
```

**TripPlaceCrossRef**:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "trip_place_cross_ref", primaryKeys = {"trip_id", "place_id"})
public class TripPlaceCrossRef {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "trip_id")
    private int tripID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_id")
    private int placeID;

    // constructors, getters, setters

}
```

**TripWithPlaces**:

```java
public class TripWithPlaces {

    @Embedded
    private Trip trip;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "trip_id",
            entityColumn = "place_id",
            associateBy = @Junction(TripPlaceCrossRef.class)
    )
    private List<Place> places;

    // constructors, getters, setters

}
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the @Update annotation form updateTrip. It's usually meant for Entities only.

Comment: @MikkelT how would I then update the trip places or delete the trip along with its places?